# Set MySQL connection string using form and save it

Tags: c#, mysql, forms, connection

I have created a project where I want to set a MySQL connection from a form.  The user can input the host, port, username, password, and database using the form. After saving the connection, the user calls the main application.

There are two applications:

1. main app(example: LoginForm)
2. connection app(example : setConnForm)

Do I have to create 2 projects or can I just do it from 1 project?

I mean, I want to create 2 application files in one project, in the Debug folder. Is that possible?

Normally, when we create a project, there is just one application file in the Debug folder to run the application.

I want 2 applications, 1 is the main application, and 2 for set connection to MySQL, so if the user runs the 1 app (loginForm) and tries to login by inputting username and password before setting the connection (app 2), the app 1 throws an exception.

Comment: You can show two forms in one application.

Answer (score -1):

you can create using one form

```
String server, password, uid, database;
private void myButton_Click(object sender, eventargs e)
{
server = textbox1.text;
password = textbox2.text;
uid = textbox3.text;
database = textbox4.text;
openConnection();
}
private bool openConnection()
    {
string connectioString= null;


        connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            return true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException wew)
        {
            switch (wew.Number)
            {
                case 0:
                    MessageBox.Show("Can not connect to server, contact administrator");
                    break;
                case 1045:
                    MessageBox.Show("Wrong Username or password, try again");
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

try that

Comment: Of course leaving a disposable object like the connection hanging around is the worst practice to advice about